# React Pass Value to onClick Function

Tags: reactjs

I wonder if there is a way to pass values to a function such as "onClick". The following code is not to be considered due to performance considerations:

```
<div onClick={() => handleClick(value)}/>
```

I'd like to write:

```
<div onClick={handleClick(value)}/>
```

But this ain't possible in React. Any solutions?

Comment: The first is a function definition, passing as a callback. The second will be executed and its result, return value will be assigned to `onClick` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually it is possible: you need to return a function that do your work.
something like this:

```js
const handleClick = value => () => {
// your logic
}
```

then use it like this:

```js
<div onClick={handleClick(value)}/>
```

Comment: It's great!. But, it works around and it's not same with: <div onClick={() => handleClick(value)}/>.

Comment: it is actually the same, you are returning a function after all.

Comment: Yes, absolutely same!

Comment: do a console log to be sure if you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your callback of a prop such as: `onClick` will pass a param event when it call. In this case, just pass a function name. Example:

```
const Comp = (props) => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        setValue(value + 1);
    }

    return <div>
        <div> {value} </div>
        {/*pass function name that declare of function have one param or don't have any pram*/}
        <button onClick={handleClick} > Click me</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: But what do you solve here? You don't pass arguments to handleClick

Comment: It will pass a `function name`. That function is used to call back when click.You can imagine, when you click button, somewhere in button controller will use the `function name` you passed. And then, it pass an event to function and call `handleClick(event)`.

Comment: Yeah ok. But where is the part that you pass an argument additionally to the event? Let's say you'd like: const handleClick = (x, y, z) => { // some code }

Comment: Because x,y,z may outer scope like what you have used in above. You can use it in function `handleClick` instead of pass it in function. What you need to pass in function is variable to pass after click like `event`. Same as with  `onClick={(event) => handleClick(value)}`